# Entity Recognition to extract question,options and diagrams from a question paper?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

Here is a sample question paper. I want to extract questions, their options and diagrams for the corresponding question(if any). Thinking of doing entity recogntion for the same. But I am not sure if that is possible for diagrams? Can someone help me out.

I tried OCR techniques previously but they are not doing well.

[image]

Comment: you have a similar [question here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/78322/image-segmentation-network-to-extract-questions-from-an-image-of-a-test-paper), you can consider merging them into one unless this is for entirely different aspect

Comment: For Named Entity Recognition, you need text. For converting this image to text, you need OCR, so you can't do NER without doing OCR first. But anyway I don't see how NER would help in any way for this task.

Comment: @Erwan Alright. Are there any OCRs which extract formulas and text both, reasonably well? I.e. more specifically would work on the question paper above?

Comment: I'm no expert but there have been a few questions about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570220/ocr-lib-for-math-formulas, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842904/ocr-for-math-formulas, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116863/image-equation-to-tex. I'd assume it would take a good bit of work to make a system separate text from formulas.